# Why are English loanwords so much more popular than Chinese ones?

Tags: linguistics

While I get that [Chinese-Japanese relations are complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanking_Massacre), [American-Japanese relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_bombings_of_Hiroshima_and_Nagasaki) [are as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internment_of_Japanese_Americans); given how Chinese jargon and terms of art are available, why is it that English terms are so often given preference?

Comment: Have you considered 漢字?

Comment: Could you give any example of jargon and art terms?

Comment: @Jimmy: Terms of art, not art terms. In this case, "term of art" actually means "jargon". An example would be 「アルミニウム」over 「軽銀」or 「鋁」.

Comment: @Williham Totland Ahh, OK. I completely read that wrong.

Comment: @Jimmy No worries: "term og art" is in and of itself a term of art.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, at least after WWII, Japanese people have been exposed to and influenced by Western cultures far more than other Asian cultures. Hollywood movies are more popular than modern Chinese movies, rock music are more popular than modern Chinese pop music, and so on. I believe the situation is more or less the same in other Asian countries, too. The majority of new and cool things come from western countries, and loanwords are no exception.

In addition, from the language perspective, Chinese jargon terms use kanji. They look too much close to old-fashioned words Japanese people have been using from more than 1000 years ago. We don't learn Chinese at school, and we don't know how to tell which Chinese words are new and cool.

Comment: This looks explanation for why you prefer English loan when you talk about things that came from English speaking countries.

Comment: I'm thinking I misinterpreted the "art" OP says and if it means ones you're talking about then the answer is it's because those things came from English speaking countries and Chinese counterparts are not available (though you call "７度" as in music in general "セブンス" in the field of pop music). Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that English terms sound more often than not foreign and vague so that you can express it without sounding too severe or direct. Or you could use it when you want to blur the discussion with fancy things. Personally I find it unintelligent to use redundant English loanwords.